# Choose selected fields of query by input using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

Is it possible to have a method that takes as input an array of strings and then use this array to create the selected fields of a query?
So if you have lets say this array:

```
var myArray []string{"fieldA","fieldB"}
```

Then you can create this automatically:

```
selectedFields := bson.M{"fieldA": 1, "fieldB": 1}
```

and then execute the query

```
result = c.Find(query).Select(selectedFields).One()
```

Comment: `myArray` is a slice BTW, not an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
func sel(q ...string) (r bson.M) {
    r = make(bson.M, len(q))
    for _, s := range q {
        r[s] = 1
    }
    return
}

result := c.Find(query).Select(sel("fieldA", "fieldB")).One() 
// or 

fields := []string{"fieldA","fieldB"}
result := c.Find(query).Select(sel(fields...)).One()
```